# Why are my "tel:" links not working

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a tableView which has cells with phone numbers.  The app is not dialing the numbers though.  See the code below

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
 if (indexPath.section == 2) {
  UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  NSString *numberToDial = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", selectedCell.detailTextLabel.text];

  NSLog(@"%@",numberToDial);

  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:numberToDial]];
 }
}
```

Console ouput:
`2010-03-08 01:32:30.830 AIB[1217:207] tel:01 8350098`

As you can see, the number goes to the console, but doesn't get dialled.  The weird thing is, if I change the last statement to this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel:171"]];
```

the phone dials the number 171 without any issue

---

The solution to my particular problem is, as suggested below, to remove the spaces from the phone numbers.  I achieved this as follows:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (indexPath.section == 2) {
        UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        NSMutableString *numberToDial = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"tel:%@", selectedCell.detailTextLabel.text];

        [numberToDial replaceOccurrencesOfString:@" " 
                                      withString:@"" 
                                         options:NSLiteralSearch 
                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [numberToDial length])];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:numberToDial]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to sanitize the user input for it to be a valid `tel://` URL. Specifically this includes stripping of:

- Spaces
- Hashes (`#`)
- Asterisks(`*`)

From [iPhone Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html):

> To prevent users from maliciously
>   redirecting phone calls or changing
>   the behavior of a phone or account,
>   the Phone application supports most,
>   but not all, of the special characters
>   in the tel scheme. Specifically, if a
>   URL contains the * or # characters,
>   the Phone application does not attempt
>   to dial the corresponding phone
>   number.

From [URLs for URLs for Telephone Calls RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2806.txt):

> ...spaces MUST NOT be used in phone
>   numbers in URLs as the space character
>   cannot be used in URLs without
>   escaping it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape spaces with for example `NSString`'s `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:` method.

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a space in the phone number.  Strip that out and try again.

Answer (score 0):

St3fan is right, you should use `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding` before constructing `NSURL` instance. iPhone OS does other magic automatically for you. If you will not percent escape problem characters then `URLWithString:` method will return nil.